# std::thread error: invalid use of void expression

Tags: c++, void

I have to send data (via TCP) from an client to a server using a socket (without using boost libraries).

My implementation in a cpp file:

```cpp
void Server::SendXBytes(int socket, unsigned int x, void* buffer)
{
    int bytesSent = 0;
    int result;
    int* bufferint = (int*)buffer;

    while (bytesSent < x)
    {
        result = read(socket, bufferint + bytesSent, x - bytesSent);

        if (result < 1)
        {
            cout << "Error sending bytes" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use it in the `main.cpp` below:

```cpp
#include "client.cpp"
#include "server.cpp"
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    int server_id;
    int socket;
    Server server(1024);
    Client client(1024);
    int server_fd = server.createSocket(server_id);
    server.PrepareSocket(server_fd);
    server.AcceptConn(server_fd, socket);
    int* buffer = new int[2000];
    std::thread client_th(client.SendXBytes(socket, 512, (void*)buffer));
    std::thread server_th(server.ReadXBytes(socket, 512, (void*)buffer));
    server_th.join();
    client_th.join();
}
```

When compile it returns me the error:

```
main.cpp:15:70: error: invalid use of void expression
  std::thread server_th(server.ReadXBytes(socket, 512, (void*)buffer));
                                                                      ^
main.cpp:16:70: error: invalid use of void expression
  std::thread client_th(client.SendXBytes(socket, 512, (void*)buffer));
```

I tried some solutions but still I have same error....

Comment: The name `bytesSent` with an `int` array is strange. Also, I'd avoid leaking naked `new` and, when possible, type casts

Comment: The arguments accepted by the constructor of `std::thread` are a function (or function object) and, optionally, a set of arguments to be passed to that function.   The thread itself will call the function.   There is no constructor that accepts the result of calling a function (unless that function returns a pointer to a function or a function object, which  your function calls do not) but that is what `main()` is passing.   Try `std::thread client_th(&Server::SendXBytes, &client, socket, 512, (void *)buffer);`

Comment: you're calling `read` instead of `write` by the way

Comment: You really don't want to share a buffer between the threads. (Why don't `Client` and `Server` manage their own buffers?)

Comment: @user253751, yes you are right...!

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
std::thread client_th(client.SendXBytes(socket, 512, (void*)buffer));
```

This directly calls the `SendXBytes` function, passing its return value (which is `void`) to the `std::thread` constructor, causing the error. What you probably meant to do was wrap that call in a lambda like this:

```cpp
std::thread client_th([&]{ client.SendXBytes(socket, 512, (void*)buffer); });
```

If you never heared of lambdas, you could maybe read up on them. Make sure you understand the implications of capturing outer variables by reference (like here) or by value using `=` instead of `&`. In this case it's okay to capture by reference, but if the thread may outlive the captured variables, it's going to lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: No need to capture by reference here.  You can capture by value and declare the lambda `mutable` if you want to call a non-`const` method.

Comment: @PaulSanders I usually go with by reference as a default as it can avoid potentially expensive copies. Both would be fine in this case though.

Comment: Actually, we have no idea what `client` and `server` are. There's a good chance they aren't even copyable.

Comment: Seems like `std::thread client_th(&Client::SendXBytes, &client, socket, 512, (void*)buffer);` would be an acceptable solution to the copyable "problem". Also avoids the use of lambdas (and capture semantics), which present something of a learning curve for people new to c++.

Comment: @Possseidon Copying `this` is cheap.

Comment: more clear now, thanks to all for the suggestions :)